# Unable to download TensorFlow for Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I want to use Tensor Flow in Java, however I cannot add it to any Java project.

So far those are the ways I tried adding it:

Using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>tensorflow-core-platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This one imported some classes, however not all that I've needed (no `org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter` for example)

Using Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.0.0-nightly'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-text:0.0.0-nightly'
```

and this Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:+'
```

Neither of those two seemed to import anything - IDE (IntelliJ) didn't detected `org.tensorfow` package in project. I suspect it might be because those might be for Android and not JVM

So my question is how can I add TS (with the `Interpreter` class) for a JVM project?